# How can I concatenate two scope and assign new value

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS JavaScript trying to concatenate two variable in order to generate or use `ng-bind-html` as I need some dynamic value to be assigned once user clicks on a button. Here are my approach:

```
$scope.addRow = function(verifier){
    $scope.count = 1;
    console.log(verifier);

    if(!angular.isUndefined(verifier)) {
        $scope.row1= $sce.trustAsHtml('<input type="text"  class="form-control"   required="required">');
        $scope.row2= $sce.trustAsHtml('<input type="text"  class="form-control"   required="required">');
        $scope.row3= $sce.trustAsHtml('<input type="text"  class="form-control"   required="required">');
        $scope.row4= $sce.trustAsHtml('<input type="text"  class="form-control"   required="required">');
        $scope.row5= $sce.trustAsHtml('<input type="text"  class="form-control"   required="required">');
        $scope.row6= $sce.trustAsHtml('<input type="text"  class="form-control"   required="required">');
        $scope.row7= $sce.trustAsHtml('<input type="text"  class="form-control"   required="required">');
    }else{
        alert('You can not add new line to balance null object');
    }
}
```

Comment: My intention is to do something inside the function like this:$scope.row+$scope.count= $sce.trustAsHtml('<input type="text"  class="form-control"

Comment: You are dosing it wrong. Explain better your goal and you will get better and simpler solution.

Comment: Actually is there a simple way of adding a rown on existing table and submit as normal considering the entry that was entered before adding new row and vice versa if new row is added continue with new input and submit thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to understand your need. You need to write like this:

```
$scope.count = 1;

$scope["row" + $scope.count] = $sce.trustAsHtml('<input type="text"  class="form-control"   required="required">');
```

Comment: This is not easy or not possible to access Scope or please if you have any idea of how i can access this new created scope help me as scope is returning NAN when combined with a number.